# Discord.py on_message перестал ловить сообщения

Tags: discord.py

5 часов назад все было нормально, но теперь бот в message.content получает = ' '
я подумал это проблема с ботом и создал еще одного в другом канале но также не работает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
mes = message.content.lower()
print(mes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, Я исправил проблему путем отключения и снова добавления прав на сообщения.

[https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/8420602109207-Нововведение-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-Имеет-ли-это-отношение-ко-мне-](https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/8420602109207-%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-)
Оказывается дискорд выпустил обнову в которой теперь ещё более защищено чтение сообщений)